# Logic help on monthly rain average program

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that uses nested loops to collect data and calculate the average rainfall over a period of years.  The program should ask the number of years.  The outer loop will iterate once for each year.  The inner loop will iterate twelve times, once for each month.  Each iteration of the inner loop will ask the user for the number of inches of rainfall for that month.

After all iterations, the program should display the nubmer of months, the total inches of rainfall and the average rainfall per month for the entire period.

```
years = int(input('How many years do you want to track? '))

months = 12

for years_rain in range(years):

total= 0.0

print('\nYear number', years_rain + 1)
print('------------------------------')
for month in range(months):
    print('How many inches for month ', month + 1, end='')
    rain = int(input(' did it rain? '))
    total += rain


number_months = years * months
average = total / number_months

print('The total inches of rain was ', format(total, '.2f'),'.')  
print('The number of months measured was', number_months)
print('The average rainfall was', format(average, '.2f'), 'inches')
```

The logic for this program is off.  It is basing the average rainfall off the last year's total rainfall, not all of the years' rainfall totals.

Where am I going wrong in the logic of this program?

Comment: Can you please check the formatting of the code? Seems unindented and not sure were the inner loop terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With properly formatted code, you'll notice that you do:

```
for years_rain in range(years):

    total= 0.0

    print('\nYear number', years_rain + 1)
    ...
```

Which *resets* the `total` to zero each iteration of your year loop. Change it instead to:

```
total = 0.0

for years_rain in range(years):  

    print('\nYear number', years_rain + 1)
    ...
```

Comment: So it was the placement of the "total" field.  I would have never gotten that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `total` value is being reset so you need a way to keep track of the `grandTotal`. Here's one way to do this:

```
years = int(input('How many years do you want to track? '))

months = 12

grandTotal = 0.0 // will store TOTAL rainfall

for years_rain in range(years):

    total= 0.0

    print('\nYear number', years_rain + 1)
    print('------------------------------')
    for month in range(months):
        print('How many inches for month ', month + 1, end='')
        rain = int(input(' did it rain? '))
        total += rain

    grandTotal += total // add total to the grandTotal

number_months = years * months
average = grandTotal / number_months

print('The total inches of rain was ', format(average, '.2f'),'.')  
print('The number of months measured was', number_months)
print('The average rainfall was', format(average, '.2f'), 'inches')
```